# Not able to get value from jsp page to ActionForm.java using struts

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have written one code to appear a text box when selecting **Other** option from a dropdown list. The function for this is as below: (I have not mention the dropdown list code, if required please let me know)

```
function showfield(name)
    {
        if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" property="otherCategory" size="25" />';

        else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
```

I am using Struts framework and have written getters/setters in registrationForm.java for **otherCategory**. But in the actionForm named registrationFormAction.java, after submitting the form, the value is not passing to the action form. Other values I am able to get. Means I am not able to get the value by `registrationForm.getOtherCategory()` in the registrationFormAction.java.

For other fields I am writing the code as

```
<html:text property="Name" size="25">
```

I also tried using `<input type="text" name="otherCategory"/>` but I am not sure how to pass the value to the action form registrationForm.java when I use **name="otherCategory"**. Hopefully I am able to explain my problem, would appreciate someone's help

Thanks. Biswa

Comment: This is struts1. Why do you tag the question with struts2?

Answer (score 1):

`property` is not a valid attribute of `<input>`. The field should be `<input type="text" name="otherCategory"/>`. If it's not submitted, it's probably because the field is outside of the form instead of being inside. But it's just a guess, since you don't provide enough code to know.

Use Firebug or the chrome developer console to know what is being submitted.

Comment: Thanks Nizet,I tried using name="otherCategory but not sure how to get the value in the actionfrom.The program flow is like

In jsp page:

function fnSubmit()
{
document.forms[0].operation.value="saveData";
document.forms[0].submit();
}

In RegistrationFormAction.java:

public ActionForward saveData(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
//how to get the otherCategory value
}

Comment: `RegistrationForm registrationForm = (RegistrationForm) form; String otherCategory = registrationForm.getOtherCategory();`. That's core struts stuff.

Comment: Thanks Nizet, it worked, actually its because of the <input type="text" property="otherCategory" size="25" />, when i changed to input type "name" it worked, thanks again...